# how to modify this code to include logging of ip address to another file

Tags: php, networking, tcp, web

please look at the simple php webpage code below

how can modify my code so that a log file is created on my server which logs each visitor's ip and whether it was successfully redirected to the correct page . something like that.

```
   <?php

$a = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ( $a == "117.96.112.122" )
{
        header("Location: ad_sams_mobile.html");
        return true;
}
else
{
        header("Location: ad_other_mobile.html");
        return true;
}

?>
```

Comment: It's not wise to rely on IP addesses to distinguish users - IP addresses can and do change.  This is particularly true when security is involved...

Comment: Judging by the contents of the script, it looks like the IP is expected to by the script owner's IP (see `ad_sams_mobile.html`) in which case he would be expecting his IP address to be static.  There's also nothing wrong with logging IP addresses for analytical purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the PHP function [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).  You'll need to use the append flag:

```
file_put_contents("log.txt", "IP: ". $a .", Location: ad_other_mobile.html", FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Apache access.log should have all the information you need.

All you have to do is parse it.

Comment: What if he's not using Apache?  Also, parsing the log programmatically would be much more difficult that simply updating a text file with the IP address.

Comment: Andy: A text file would still need to be parsed if any analysis were to be done on the logs and if no analysis needs to be done, then whats the point of logging. At the end of the day, parsing is an unavoidable pain. If you're too lazy to parse log files, maybe a DB would do, but honestly, how difficult can a grep be? With that said I expect all web servers to have some kind of access log, Apache and IIS do, I know for sure. As far as I can tell, logging from your PHP app is reinventing the wheel while adding unnecessary overheads to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$logfile = 'redirect.log';
$handle = @fopen($logfile, "a");

$a = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ( $a == "117.96.112.122" )
{
    $redirect_loc = 'ad_sams_mobile.html';
    header("Location: {$redirect_loc}");
 }
else
{
    $redirect_loc = 'ad_other_mobile.html';
    header("Location: {$redirect_loc}");
}

if ($handle && is_writable($logfile))
{
    $log = "{$a} -> {$redirect_loc}\n";
    fwrite($handle, $log);
    fclose($handle);
}
return true; // you always return true so just put it at the end
```

Comment: I prefer file_put_contents, you don't need to open a handle to the file or check that it's writable, it will just return false if it can't write.

Comment: Wasn't sure and didn't bother to check actually so I just made a double precaution. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

Or this for IP logging:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("log.html", "a");

$time = date("H:i dS F");
fwrite($file, "<b>Time:</b> $time<br/>" );

if( $REMOTE_ADDR != null)
{
fwrite($file,"<b>IP address:</b> $REMOTE_ADDR<br/>");
}

if( $HTTP_REFERER != null)
{
fwrite($file,"<b>Referer:</b> $HTTP_REFERER<br/>");
}

fwrite($file,"<b>Browser:</b> $HTTP_USER_AGENT<hr/>");

fclose($file)

?>
```

Comment: > $HTTP_USER_AGENT
Seriously, start using SuperGlobals. Will save you tons of headaces once your PHP Server Administrator decides to finally set register_globals to false (as it should be). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.register-globals